# Cookie problems with javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I setup a jQuery plugin > http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html to countdown from 3 days.

The time should not start over on refresh. It should continue where it left off when the user comes back let's say 1/2 days later. After 3 days it should just reload.

Everything looks right. But it's not working. Numbers are showing up as NaN.

If the "until: new Date(cookie)" is changed to "+2d" as is standard for the plugin it works fine. When its changed to the date 3 days ahead with the cookie it fails.

Anyone know what's wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (!$.cookie('offerTimer')){
    var now = new Date(); 
    timer = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + 3);
    $.cookie('offerTimer', timer.format("yyyy, mm, dd"), { expires: 7, path: '/' });
}

var cookie = $.cookie('offerTimer');

$('#until3d').countdown({until: new Date(cookie), format: 'HMS'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the timer variable as a [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object.  There is no format method on the Date object, so timer.format("yyyy, mm, dd") will generate an error.

You just need to save the timer variable.  It will be converted to a string in the cookie, and you've already put in the code to convert that string back into a Date object when you read it.

So this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if (!$.cookie('offerTimer')) {
    var now = new Date();
    timer = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + 3);
    $.cookie('offerTimer', timer, {
      expires: 7,
      path: '/'
    });
  }

  var cookie = $.cookie('offerTimer'), 
    theDate;

  if (new Date(cookie) > new Date()) {
    theDate = new Date(cookie);
  } else {
    // if the cookie date has passed, then set the time date to now (so hopefully it just stays at zero)
    theDate = new Date();
  }
  $('#until3d').countdown({
    until: theDate,
     format: 'HMS'
  }); 


});
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you. What if...if/when the timer reaches 0, then it just disappears. I don't want to have a string issue again. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your question?

Comment: When the countdown reaches 0, it just disappears